# Is it possible to upload a new version of an APK with a different key while in alpha testing

Tags: android, certificate, apk, developer-console

Okay so here is the situation.
A month ago, I uploaded and published our first alpha app on the play store. It's a closed alpha and can be downloaded via a link.
The private key / keystore I used to upload this was a debug one (Valid for 1 year as that is the default I think).

Unfortunately, my computer was wiped before I could backup the used key. I figured out later that I cannot upload a new version of the app because I don't have the key anymore and that apps cannot be deleted from the app store, only unpublished.

Is this any different for alpha testing apps? And can I somehow delete / use a new key to upload a new version?

If not, I find it a bit strange that it is possible to use a debug key that only lasts for a year for alpha testing, while you cannot exchange it for a production key later...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

refer [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) for Update your apps

Comment: Okay thank you, just created a new app with new package name